# Remove brackets in print

Tags: tcl, brackets

I am a new tcl user.
I am trying to type white space for output file.
I am using the `lappend` command:

```
lappend lineM1 [ format "%-4s" "     " ]
set outfile [open "test" w]
    puts $outfile "$lineM1"
    close $outfile
```

This is what I get:

```
{     }
```

How can I remove the brackets? How do I print just white space?

Comment: You'll learn to be more disciplined about using list commands on lists and string commands on strings.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure about what you want to do, but if you replace the
`lappend` with a `set lineM1`. You don't get the brackets.

The tcl command [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/lappend.htm) is a `list` command. It appends the result of `format "%-4s" "     "` to the not yet existing list `lineM1`.

By the way, if you just want to print white space into the `$outfile` you don't need to `format` that white space. Perhaps you should have a look at the [format manual page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/format.htm).

Example:

```
set foo "bar"
puts $foo
```

Will result in:

```
bar
```

In your case you would add the file handle  `$outfile` to the `puts` call:

```
puts $outfile $foo
```

The [tcl.tk wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/298) is a good resource for starters.